# MLE of Poisson-Gamma distribution?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, poisson-distribution, gamma-distribution

I am trying to create an example that applies fully parametric estimation. I am using a Gamma-Poisson distribution where the random variable is a Poisson random variable with mean $\lambda$ which has a Gamma distribution with parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Also denoted as $X \sim \textrm{Gamma-Poisson}(\alpha,\beta)$ with probability mass function

\begin{equation*}
f(x) = \frac{\Gamma{(x+\beta)}\alpha^{x}}{\Gamma(\beta)(1+\alpha)^{\beta+x}x!} \;\;\; x=0,1,2,...
\end{equation*}

I am familiar with solving for MLE's but not entirely sure with this distribution. Currently what I have is below but I'm not sure about the $\Gamma$ function.

\begin{align*}
L(\theta) &= \prod_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\Gamma{(x_i+\beta)}\alpha^{x_i}}{\Gamma(\beta)(1+\alpha)^{\beta+x_i}x_i!}
\\
\textrm{ln} \; L(\theta) &= \sum_{i=1}^{n} \textrm{ln} \left(\frac{\Gamma{(x_i+\beta)}\alpha^{x_i}}{\Gamma(\beta)(1+\alpha)^{\beta+x_i}x_i!}\right)
\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n} \big[\textrm{ln}\:\Gamma{(x_i+\beta)} + x_i\:\textrm{ln}\:\alpha - \textrm{ln}\:\Gamma(\beta) - (\beta+x_i)\:\textrm{ln}\:(1+\alpha) - \textrm{ln}\:(x_i!)\big]
\\
& \; \vdots
\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial\alpha}\;\textrm{ln}\;L(\theta) &= \dots = 0
\\
\hat{\alpha} &=
\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial\beta}\;\textrm{ln}\;L(\theta) &= \dots = 0
\\
\hat{\beta} &= 
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to solve this arithmetically, numerical analysis is required to find the MLE for beta distribution (and subsequently the distribution you are discussing here).

https://www.real-statistics.com/distribution-fitting/distribution-fitting-via-maximum-likelihood/fitting-beta-distribution-parameters-mle/

Answer (score 1):

You can solve for  in terms of , and for  you need to work with the [Digamma Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function).